# How to unlink library from react-native project

Tags: react-native

I installed this library (https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) following the installation instructions

```
npm install react-native-localization --save
react-native link react-native-localization
```

and I don't want to use it anymore. I already tried the following steps to remove it from my project:

```
npm unlink react-native-localization
npm uninstall react-native-localization --save
```

I tried to run

```
react-native unlink react-native-localization
```

However, I get the error message that `react-native-localization is not a react-native library.`

When I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-localization.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-localization:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Answer (score 20):

First run

```
react-native unlink libraryname
```

then

```
npm uninstall libraryname
```

or using `yarn`

```
yarn remove libraryname
```

In case, if it's not working then

Go to your project android directory and open **setting.gradle**

and remove your library configration manualy. and

also check your **MainActivity.java** to remove any configration about library.

Hope it will help!!!

Comment: If you're using yarn. Run 'yarn remove libraryname' instead of 'npm uninstall libraryname'

Comment: How would it be done today, when we no longer have the unlink command? When I try I get `error Unrecognized command "unlink"`

Comment: how do it on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the solution. You have to remove the reference in the build.gradle file in your Android project and also any references in the MainApplication.java class. Then it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is that first unlink the library and then remove library from package.json.

So run command in below order:

First unlink library :

> react-native unlink react-native-localization

And then remove npm reference :

> npm uninstall react-native-localization --save

Answer (score 0):

- react-native uninstall --save LIBRARY_NAME

after uninstall library you need to remove reference manually

ANDROID : 
- Project Directory/settings.gradle
- remove below line

```
include ':react-native-abc' //Your library name
project(':react-native-abc').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-abc/android-exoplayer')
```

also remove reference from MainApplication.java 
- Project Directory/App/main/java/MainApplication.java
- remove incude

```
import abc; // your library
```

- remove package

```
new abc()
```

IOS :
- remove reference from pod file

```
pod 'abc', :path => '../node_modules/abc'
```

- cd ios
- pod install

Answer (score -1):

> ***react-native unlink libraryname***

For Example:- unlink react-native-localization pluggin
then write this command in terminal

```
react-native unlink react-native-localization
```

Comment: OP wrote "*I tried to run `react-native unlink react-native-localization`*"