# React Native Fingerprint Scanner taking too much time to authenticate

Tags: react-native

I'm using "react-native-fingerprint-scanner": "^6.0.0" it works fine on emulator. But when I built apk it taking too much time(3 or 4 second) to authenticate on a real device. What can i do?

Here is my code:

const SplashBeforeFingerprint = ({ navigation }) => {

```
useEffect(() => {
        FingerprintScanner
            .authenticate({ description: 'Scan your fingerprint on the device scanner to continue' })
            .then(() => {
                    /// nothing to do
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Authentication failed",
                    "Your fingerprint doesn't matches! Try agin later!",
                    [
                        {
                            text: "Exit",
                            onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp(),
                            style: "cancel"
                        },

                    ],
                    { cancelable: false });
            });

}, []);

return (
    <ImageBackground source={require("../img/Splash2.png")} style={styles.imageContainer} >
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer} >
            <AppButton style={styles.button} textStyle={styles.text} name={"Go to Home"} onPress={() => navigation.reset({
                index: 2,
                routes: [{ name: 'NewWallet' }],
            })} />

        </View>
    </ImageBackground>
) }
```

Comment: Three questions - 1. Is it possible the APK was built for debug instead of release?  Debug will be much slower.
2. Is the device slow in general?
3. If the Fingerprint method is connecting to an external API, could there be network issues with the device?

Comment: The answer to your questions is - 1. it is a signed APK. 2. Device has 4GB ram. 3. There is no external API. only given code was used for fingerprint. @Abe

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment. I had similar problem.
Behavior: first run of the screen - nothing happens, after around 10 seconds, it showed dialog to auth.
If auth was ok or canceled, later it opened imidiately.

I installed these packages: react-native-pincode, @react-native-async-storage/async-storage and react-native-keychain.

So, solution was to uninstall them.
Folow answer from this post: [How to unlink library from react-native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909241/how-to-unlink-library-from-react-native-project)

- unlink
- uninstall
- comment imports in setting.gradle and MainActivity.java (if not done, you will not be able to compile your project)
- gradlew clean
  and recompile e.g. npx react-native run-android